# Microsoft SQL @@cpu_busy replacement for CPU saturation stat

Tags: sql, sql-server, sybase

We have a process that was originally written for Sybase that looks at the @@cpu_busy variables to detect the cpu load on the RDMS.  The application will be running against Microsoft SQL.

```
     curCPULoadPercent=100*(@@cpu_busy - prevCpuBusy)/((@@cpu_busy - prevCpuBusy)+(@@io_busy - prevIOBusy)+(@@idle - prevIdle))
```

If any of the above deltas are negative, the ratio is ignore and the previous one is used.

Unfortunately, instead of letting the number roll over, the Microsoft engineers stop increasing the number (134217727) and thus fails to reveal CPU load after 29 days (from what I have been reading).

(The Sybase engineers knew that a negative number subtracted from a negative number gives a positive difference.)

The following provides a hint on how to monitor CPU load, but we are unable to determine which wait types to look at.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179984.aspx

We have been measuring the @@cpu_busy differences compared to the wait types and not any particular wait type matches.

Our plan is to build a predictive model to predict the old ratio from correlated wait types but I am wondering if someone has already figured this out.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Benjamin Nevarez has the answer for CPU utilization:

http://sqlblog.com/blogs/ben_nevarez/archive/2009/07/26/getting-cpu-utilization-data-from-sql-server.aspx

It uses Dynamic Mgmt View data from sys.dm_os_ring_buffers
where ring_buffer_type = N'RING_BUFFER_SCHEDULER_MONITOR'.

Answer (score 0):

starting with SQL2005 the runtime detail that you can get from SQL Server for things like Wait types and locks and load and memory  pressure are extremely detailed and varied.

Do not use @@ variables for what you are doing.  If you can define exactly what you are trying to detect I can guarantee that the newer sql views have exactly what your are looking for and in particular the values can be defined in a spid or overall context.

The SQL Profiler tools can graph the values you are looking for probably.

Comment: Agreed, I do not want to use the @@ variables. I need something to report the CPU utilization percentage and the IO utilization percentage.

Comment: You can use WMI to get those counters directly from the OS.  To use that value from within a stored proc seems problematic as its value has almost no meaning within an individual spid context.    I have always accomplished things like a governor by having the running action part of my query know how to self control itself such as running only once per minute or once per 10 min.

Comment: Is there a way to access WMI remotely?

Comment: Is there a way of resetting the @@vars short of a restart?